# Python Selenium Can't use move_to_element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.get('https://datahub.ren.pt/en/electricity/monthly-balance/')
driver.maximize_window()

a = ActionChains(driver)


WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/section[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a[1]'))).click()
 
driver.close()
```

I'm trying to write code to click a link that only appears when the mouse is over a button but the move_to_element used in other solutions doesn't work for me, I need to place the mouse manually for the program to click the link, does anyone know of a working alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'move_by_offset' instead. It's used for moving the mouse to an offset from current mouse position. To automate the browser create a webdriver instance:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://datahub.ren.pt/en/electricity/monthly-balance/')
driver.maximize_window()

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/section[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a[1]')))
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(button).perform()

link_location = button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Change the x and y value to match the position of the link to the button.

```
link_x_offset = 100
link_y_offset = 0
action.move_by_offset(link_location['x'] + link_x_offset, link_location['y'] + link_y_offset).click().perform()
driver.close()
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, the mouse doesn't move at all.